using the word "each" in a claim
a computer implemented method, comprising:
enabling at least one special input widget on each electronic device of the plurality of users, each special input widget having at least three buttons;

Questions:

If there is an input widget on a user's device that just has two buttons, would this input widget simply be interpreted to be of a type different from a "special" input widget?
And if this is the case, it alone would still not bypass infringement since the claim does not exclude other types of input widgets, correct?
So for example, if a user's device has an input widget with three buttons and another input widget with only two buttons, this still infringes, correct?


I would recommend changing "the plurality of users" to "a plurality of users".

So for example, if a user's device has an input widget with three buttons and another input widget with only two buttons, this still infringes, correct?

Yes. But suppose there is a user who has only an input widget with two buttons. One would not consider this user as part of said plurality of users.
So as long as there are at least two users on whom one enables the special input widget on every electronic device belonging to or associated with the two users, the claim would be infringed.
Each is still profanity because users may own or be associated with a diverse array of electronic devices, not all of which are suitable for running the special input widget.
Maybe you want to limit somehow to devices that have been activated or registered with a particular service.
I don't know the details but it seems to be that you might be reciting something that is not a key aspect of the invention in excessive detail. That could result in an unnecessarily narrow claim.
